# Override digital crown action in certain conditions (MapKit UI with custom interactions)?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, watchos

Designing a WatchOS 17 app to trigger an alarm when you're arriving to a destination.  Simple UI of a fullscreen MapKit map.  If you tap the screen, a Marker is placed at the location and then confirm (set the alarm) or cancel (remove the marker) buttons appear.  In this stage (before confirmation), I want to be able to control a radius (visualised by MapCircle) within which the alarm will trigger.  I want this radius controllable with the digital crown (which automatically controls the map zoom).  This means, that in that particular application state, the map zoom control should be overridden - there's limited documentation online, only the simple read digital crown value stuff which requires the field be focussed (I don't actually want the slider below to be visible, but I can't find any other way to theoretically use the crown unless focus is on an element).

Theoretically... in practice, there doesn't seem to be any automatic way (.onAppear?) of shifting the focus to a new element.  I've also tried manually taping on the element (slider focus never overrides the map zoom, tapping on a focusable text element does but its buggy an seems to want to revert to the map zoom.

How do???

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum FocusedField {
            case slider, map
        }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?

    @State var pinLocation :CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil
    @State var scrollAmount = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            
            
            //          MAP VIEW START
            MapReader{ reader in
                Map()
                {
                    if let pl = pinLocation {
                        Marker("", coordinate: pl)
                    }
                    if let pl = pinLocation {
                        MapCircle(center: pl, radius: CLLocationDistance(floatLiteral: scrollAmount))
                    }
                }
                .focusable()
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .map)
                .onTapGesture(perform: { screenCoord in
                    pinLocation = reader.convert(screenCoord, from: .local)
                })
            }
            //          MAP VIEW END
            
            
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                
                
                //              BOTTOM BAR VIEW START
                if (pinLocation != nil) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            pinLocation = nil
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "multiply")
                        })
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        })
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .safeAreaPadding(.all, 15.0)
                }
                //              BOTTOM BAR VIEW END
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            if(pinLocation != nil) {
                Slider(value: $scrollAmount)
                    .focusable()
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .slider)
                    .onAppear {
                        focusedField = .slider
                    }
                    .digitalCrownRotation($scrollAmount)
            }
            
            
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: further testing shows behaviour works EXACTLY as intended if the map content (pin and circle) block is removed.  so i tested including the block but removing the binding to the radius and again it is working exactly as intended.  the dynamic change in radius is pulling focus from the slider.